# Как отправить гиперссылку через бота Telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot, гиперссылка

Пытаюсь через botmother сделать бота. Есть такая ссылка, которая срабатывает при нажатии кнопки:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:ABCDE/sendMessage?chat_id=CHATID&text=ОХАЁ.+Вот+[ссылка](url.com)+на+текст.
```

Но этот способ возвращает только

```
ОХАЁ. Вот [ссылка](url.com) на текст.
```

Через POST запрос

```
{
"chat_id": "{{this_user.platform_id}}",
"text": "ОХАЁ. Вот [ссылка](url.com) на текст."
}
```

тоже не получается, потому что опять же возвращается

```
ОХАЁ. Вот [ссылка](url.com) на текст.
```

Возможно ли как-то внедрить гиперссылку сюда, чтобы сообщение присылалось как задумано?

> ОХАЁ. Вот [ссылка](https://url.com) на текст.

Comment: ```parse_mode=HTML&text=ОХАЁ. Вот <a href='url.com'>ссылка</a> на текст.```, можно и в маркдауне оформить, но я честно не помню как, там какая то хитрость была. если в рабочее время пинганете - найду как это делалось...

Comment: Добавьте параметр [parse_mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) со значением [Markdown](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style) (устаревший способ) или [MarkdownV2](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style). При использовании MarkdownV2 не забудьте экранировать спецсимволы (об этом сказано в документации), например, обычная точка `.` должна выглядеть как `\.`

Answer (score 0):

parse_mode=HTML&text=ОХАЁ. `Вот <a href='url.com'>ссылка</a> на текст`, можно и в маркдауне оформить.